# JS file works fine on IE but not on other browsers

Tags: javascript, ajax

The function below gets results in ie but not on the other browsers. Any suggestion?

```
function show_packet(str, company) {
    var cam = document.getElementById("company");
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        var xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("packet_1").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            document.getElementById("icon_1").innerHTML = "";
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "show_packet.php?car_moto=" + encodeURIComponent(str, true) + "&cam=" + encodeURIComponent(cam.value, true));
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: What do you see in the console?

Comment: On ie 10 it is ok and on the console. On Modzilla Web Console it seems like it runs the file 2 times

Answer (score -1):

vars and functions are hoisted to the top of their containing function. Declare your var once at the top, and only assign it in the if/else.

Comment: I fail to see how that applies here.

Comment: I thought the effect might be that it would overwrite the value by hoisting the assignment. I just tried a test, and that is not the case.

Comment: Javascript doesn't have the same scope rules as Java/C++ etc